# Бесконечное подключение клиента minecraft к серверу papermc, через ipv6. (vps джино)

Tags: java, vps, minecraft, ipv6, bukkit

По дурости купил vps для сервера майнкрафт на "Джуно", оказалось что выделенные ipv4 не входит в тариф. В propertis пробовал по разному как указывать так и не указывать ipv6, но всё равно идёт бесконечное подключение клиента.
Пробовал привязать домен но так и не понял даже как это делать. Зарегистрировал бесплатный домен на
freedomain для теста, в панели управления смог только найти чтобы просто указать его, но никаких там я даже не знаю кодов или прочего нет, я не совсем понимаю как это работает. В итоге через домен всего что я добился это сообщения "Неизвестный сервер"

При этом сам сервер вроде нормально запускается.

Однако discordSrv в discord пишет: "* назад @Nik, сервер не ответил через 30 секунд"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приобретение домена не поможет, так как домен это маска ip

К примеру example.ru перебрасывает клиента на 192.168. Буквенный домен это как перенаправление.

В вашей ситуации или докупать ipv4 или использовать RadminVPN or Hamachi

Comment: Спасибо большое!